# Compilation Problem When Trying To Use qobject_cast To Const Pointer

Tags: c++, qt

I'm implementing low level plugins in Qt, but stumbled upon a weird compilation error.

When I try to use qobject_cast to cast the plugin instance to a **const** interface pointer it tells me that the interface itself should inherit QObject and make use of Q_OBJECT macro.

However when I use qobject_cast to cast to a **non-const** interface pointer it compiles just fine.

I have an interface:

```
class PluginInterface
{

public:
    PluginInterface(const QString &string);
    virtual void doSomething() const = 0;

protected:
    QString string;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(PluginInterface, "PluginInterface")
```

And an implementation:

```
class PLUGINSHARED_EXPORT Plugin : public QObject, public PluginInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(PluginInterface)
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "Plugin")

public:
    Plugin();

    void doSomething() const;
};
```

When trying to compile with qobject_cast casting to a const pointer it complains that PluginInterface should inherit from QObject and use Q_OBJECT macro.

```
    QPluginLoader loader("C:/Users/Henrique/Documents/Qt Projects/PluginTest/Plugin.dll");

    const PluginInterface *interface = qobject_cast<const PluginInterface *>(loader.instance());

    interface->doSomething();
```

However this compiles just fine, that is, casting to a non-const PluginInterface pointer.

```
    QPluginLoader loader("C:/Users/Henrique/Documents/Qt Projects/PluginTest/Plugin.dll");

    const PluginInterface *interface = qobject_cast<PluginInterface *>(loader.instance());

    interface->doSomething();
```

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because macro `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` does not implement this feature.

`Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` definition:

```
#  define Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IFace, IId) \
    template <> inline const char *qobject_interface_iid<IFace *>() \
    { return IId; } \
    template <> inline IFace *qobject_cast<IFace *>(QObject *object) \
    { return reinterpret_cast<IFace *>((object ? object->qt_metacast(IId) : nullptr)); } \
    template <> inline IFace *qobject_cast<IFace *>(const QObject *object) \
    { return reinterpret_cast<IFace *>((object ? const_cast<QObject *>(object)->qt_metacast(IId) : nullptr)); }
#endif // Q_MOC_RUN
```

As we can see, this macro contains only these `qobject_cast` functions: `template <> inline IFace *qobject_cast<IFace *>(QObject *object)` and `template <> inline IFace *qobject_cast<IFace *>(const QObject *object)`.